# Convert ImageMagick’s output from scientific to decimal?

Tags: unix, image-processing, terminal, imagemagick, pipe

I have a small one-liner in terminal which is to write the pixel count of many JPEG files to a text file:

```
find . -name *.jpg -exec convert {} -format "%[fx:w*h]" info: \; > sizes.txt
```

It actually does, but some of the numbers are in scientific notation, like here:

```
949200
960000
1.098e+06
1.038e+06
1.1664e+06
1.0824e+06
831600
```

What is the most robust / elegant way to have the commands output just in decimal notation, like in the following lines?

```
949200
960000
109806
103806
1166406
1082406
831600
```

I was wondering if you would do this within the ImageMagick *fx* part or rather pipe the output to another command for conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php
there is no obvious way to get other number formats with the %fx:
directive, so a command line solution is necessary.

Converting the w*h scientific notation output will lose you significant
digits, so better output w and h separately and multiply.

Using bc this would be:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec convert {} -format "%w*%h" info: \; |bc
```

Comment: Thanks! I could use `identify -format "%w %h" <filename>` -- but then how do I multiply _w_ and _h_ in this stream of pipes? Is it possible?

Comment: I have added a line using _bc_

Answer (score 2):

To have ImageMagick print numbers larger than one million without truncating them to exponential (scientific) notation, use the `-precision n` option. The default precision is 6. I suggest setting it to 12, which allows numbers up to 1e+12 (a 1 followed by twelve zeros).

```
$ convert xc: -precision 12 -format '%[fx:1000*1000]\n' info:-
1000000

$ convert xc: -precision 6 -format '%[fx:1000*1000]\n' info:-
1e+06
```

Answer (score 0):

This modification to the shell command seems to work:

```
find . -name *.jpg -exec convert {} -format "%[fx:w*h]" info: \;  | xargs printf "%0.0f\n" > sizes.txt
```

Adjust the formatting directives `printf "%0.0f\n"` to suit your needs.

Just for demonstration purposes (this works the same with find etc and .jpg files found on my system):

```
$ cat data.txt

949200
960000
1.098e+06
1.038e+06
1.1664e+06
1.0824e+06
831600

$ cat data.txt | xargs printf "%0.0f\n"

949200
960000
1098000
1038000
1166400
1082400
831600
```

Comment: Hmmm... the `printf` command gives me `printf: 1.09056e+06: not completely converted` for non-decimal values

Comment: Oh, sorry! I’m on `/bin/bash` in OS X 10.6